# Convert 2D array to String and String to 2D String again in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing

I have an array looking like this:

```
String private String array[][];

array = [["smthng","smthng","smthng","smthng"],
["smthng","smthng","smthng","smthng"]];
```

I want to convert it to String to store it and then convert it to 2D array again but I always get indexoutboundexception.

I tried this:

```
private String twoDimensionalStringArrayToString(String[][] myArray) throws IOException {
    String res = "";
    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < myArray.length; iRow++) {
        for (int iCol = 0; iCol < myArray[iRow].length; iCol++)
            res += myArray[iRow][iCol] + ",";
        res += "\n";
    }
    return res;
}

private String[][] stringToTwoDimensionalStringArray(String res) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

    String[] rows = res.split("\n");
    String[][] myArray = new String[rows.length][];
    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < rows.length-1; iRow++) {
        String[] cols = rows[iRow].split(",");
        myArray[iRow] = new String[cols.length];
        for (int iCol = 0; iCol < cols.length; iCol++)
            myArray[iRow][iCol] = cols[iCol];
    }
    return myArray;
}
```

Then I do this to save the String:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("MAPA", twoDimensionalStringArrayToString(mapa));
```

And This to read it:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
mapa = stringToTwoDimensionalStringArray(sharedPref.getString("MAPA", null));
```

Comment: Can we see what you tried?

Comment: Please provide the piece of code

Comment: I've edit the question with the code.

Comment: It´s running without an exception for me with the given array. It should be ok.

Comment: despite that, the inner loop in your `stringToTwoDimensionalStringArray` is unneccesarry. You can directly assign `cols` to `myArray[iRow]` as `myArray[iRow] = cols;`.

Comment: Not working for me, I've added more code to the question.